# How to use static role in Loopback ACL

Tags: loopbackjs

The static role in Loopback ACL not working.

I created a new user (id=2, see table below) with no rules and even then I could access the endpoint "changeprice".

What did I do wrong?

**common/models/product.json**

```
"acls": [
    {
       "accessType": "*",
       "principalType": "ROLE",
       "principalId": "$everyone",
       "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
       "accessType": "READ",
       "principalType": "ROLE",
       "principalId": "$everyone",
       "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
       "accessType": "EXECUTE",
       "principalType": "ROLE",
       "principalId": "admin",
       "permission": "ALLOW",
       "property": "changePrice"
    }
]
```

**common/models/product.js**

```
module.exports = function(Product) {
   Product.changePrice = function(cb) {
       response = "Pong!";
       cb(null, response);
   };

   Product.remoteMethod (
       'changePrice',
       {
           http: {path: '/changeprice', verb: 'get'},
           returns: {arg: 'message', type: 'string'}
       }
   );
};
```

**User Table**

```
 +----+----------+
 | id | username |
 +----+----------+
 | 1  | Teste    |
 +----+----------+
 | 2  | Teste2   |
 +----+----------+
```

**Role Table**

```
 +----+-------+
 | id | name  |
 +----+-------+
 | 1  | admin |
 +----+-------+
```

**RoleMapping Table**

```
 +----+---------------+-------------+--------+
 | id | principalType | principalId | roleId |
 +----+---------------+-------------+--------+
 | 1  | USER          | 1           | 1      |
 +----+---------------+-------------+--------+
```

Comment: Can you share how you're assigning role to user 1?

Comment: @VishalKumar Through RoleMapping table. The loopback apply the permissions according to this table?